Is there a limit to the number of Windows VPN dial-ups?
I encountered a strange problem when using a Windows system for VPN dial-up.
In my work scenario, I need to use Windows system to connect to several customer networks at the same time through VPN (PPTP, L2TP, etc.) and maintain the connection:

If I do VPN dial-up (L2TP) on Windows Server 2012, there is no problem if the number of simultaneous dial-ups (and keeping connections) does not exceed 5
When there are already 5 VPN (L2TP) dial-up connections successfully, if I try to dial up the 6th VPN (L2TP) at this time, it will fail: error code 633
But if I make the 6th VPN (PPTP) dial-up at this time (not L2TP type), there will be no problem
On my Windows 10 system, the upper limit of simultaneous VPN (L2TP) dial-up is 2, and the third VPN (L2TP) dial-up will fail: the error code is also 633
No matter I use rasdial.exe to test in the command line, or I use the API RasDial function to test, this problem of the upper limit of simultaneous dialing will appear.
I tried adjusting the order of VPN dial-up, but the problem still persists.
I tried this solution from Microsoft, (["Error 633 - the modem (or other connecting device) is already in use" error message when you try to establish a VPN connection][1]), but it didn’t work, I did not find that port 1723 is occupied

I have not tested on more different versions of Windows systems.
This question gives me the impression that the Windows operating system has a built-in upper limit on the number of VPNs of the same type that can be dialed at the same time? Moreover, this upper limit is different on different Windows operating systems.
I haven't found any information related to this problem online, or am I looking for it in the wrong way?
If there is indeed a built-in upper limit, is there any way to increase the upper limit?
Thanks.

MS lists that error as:

Error 633: The modem or connecting device is already in use or is not configured properly

Given 5 devices are fine but 6 fails, most likely you have a /29 subnet configured for client IP's. A /29 subnet gives you 8 IP's, but 3 will already be used (Network, Broadcast and the VPN endpoint itself) leaving you with 5 IP's.
Hence the sixth connection is failing because there aren't any additional IP's available for the new connection. To fix it you will need to reconfigure the VPN endpoint to give it a larger IP pool.
